# i want only success/fail message after call Ajax by AngularJS in php file . but i got full HTML page code with tag also

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, angularjs

i want only success/fail message after call Ajax by AngularJS in php file . but i got full HTML page code with tag also

My AngularJS code:

```
$http.post('ajax_Location.php',{
'uname': $scope.user.name, 
'uid': $scope.user.id,
'uemail':$scope.user.email}).
success(function(data, status, headers, config) {$scope.myData.fromServer = data;});
```

My php code:

```
<?php
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$uname = mysql_real_escape_string($data->uname);
$uid = mysql_real_escape_string($data->uid);
$uemail = mysql_real_escape_string($data->uemail);
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root"; $password = "";
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password); 
$db=mysqli_select_db($conn,'mydbtest');
$sql='INSERT INTO formdetails (firstName,lastName,enrollNumber) VALUES ("'.$uname.'","'.$uemail.'",'.$uid.')';
$inserts=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
echo "Record inserted successfully ";
?>
```

Comment: what's your question? what's the content of ajax_location.php what is it supposed to do?

Comment: AngularJS  actually there is my php file and there is DB connectivity code which work properlly but when success message i'm going to display it return hole html tag and data like " <h1>success</h1> "

Comment: can you add the php code?

Comment: <?php
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$uname = mysql_real_escape_string($data->uname);
$uid = mysql_real_escape_string($data->uid);
$uemail = mysql_real_escape_string($data->uemail);
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password);
$db=mysqli_select_db($conn,'mydbtest');
$sql='INSERT INTO formdetails (firstName,lastName,enrollNumber) VALUES ("'.$uname.'","'.$uemail.'",'.$uid.')';
$inserts=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
echo "Record inserted successfully ";
?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your `php` file -

```
<?php 
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input")); 
$uname = mysql_real_escape_string($data->uname); 
$uid = mysql_real_escape_string($data->uid); 
$uemail = mysql_real_escape_string($data->uemail); 
$servername = "localhost"; 
$username = "root"; 
$password = ""; 
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password); 
$db=mysqli_select_db($conn,'mydbtest'); 
$sql='INSERT INTO formdetails (firstName,lastName,enrollNumber) VALUES ("'.$uname.'","'.$uemail.'",'.$uid.')'; 
$inserts=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
echo json_encode(array("successfully")); 
exit;
?>
```

Comment: hmm itz working but at the html page where i'm going to show the success message in div tag the result is like this {"success":"Record inserted successfully"}  instead of   Record inserted successfully  ... i mean it is not return as a html format or wt??? ...  sry i'm new for angularJS so ..

Comment: change it as you want..updating the answer